# node-gyp using node version

Tags: nodes, node-gyp

I'm in a docker image; running ubuntu 16
I updated node using

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n lts
```

I now get the below console output

```
node -v 
v12.18.2
```

I need to rebuilt a node-gyp binding

```
node-gyp configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.0.3
gyp info using node@4.2.6 | linux | x64
```

And the output that creates errors when I try to run it with

```
Error: The module '/root/gzweb/gzbridge/build/Debug/gzbridge.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

Which makes sense.

My questions
Where does node-gyp pick up its node from?
How do I update node-gyp?
How do I update the version of node that node-gyp wants to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I needed to re-run `npm install -g node-gyp` after the node update; then it picked up a newer version of node-gyp